# How do I preserve case when doing a replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using JQuery and want to write a function where I highlight all occurrences of a word.  So I wrote the function

```
function highlight(elt, text, hexCode) {
    let inputText = $(elt).html();
    let index = inputText.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase());
    let openSpanTag = "<span style='background-color:" + hexCode + ";'>";
    let closeSpanTag = "</span>";
    let replacement = openSpanTag + text + closeSpanTag;
    let innerHTML = inputText.replace(new RegExp(text, 'gi'), replacement);
    $(elt).html(innerHTML);
}
```

The only issue I'm having is the replacement isn't preserving the case of the word.  For example, if the word is "hello" and the string is "HELLO WORLD", the replacement is coming out as

```
<span background-color='orange'>hello</span> WORLD
```

but I would like it to be

```
<span background-color='orange'>HELLO</span> WORLD
```

What do I need to do to preserve the case?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Actually you should not be thinking of replacing, but of **inserting** what you need at the *start* and *end* indexes.

Comment: @PeterB, with the start and end indexes, doesn't that break down if there is more than one occurrence of the string?  That is, once you do the replace of the first instance, doesn't that throw off the indexes that you've already gathered?